# Where the location of code section of a process in linux?

Tags: linux

I want to restore the stack and heap when process is down. So I must make sure that the address of the function stays the same every time it starts, if the binary stays the same.

Is there anyone could help?

Comment: You're looking for this, right? - https://linux-audit.com/elf-binaries-on-linux-understanding-and-analysis/.

Comment: Thank you.I just want to make sure that the address of the function stays the same every time it starts, if the binary stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If address-space layout randomisation is enabled — which is the case on most current Linux systems — then no, function addresses don’t stay the same every time a binary is loaded. There are various different layout randomisations which are applied, and if the binary is position-independent, all of them can be applied; in particular, library ASLR means that libraries are loaded in a different place every time, and execution ASLR means that position-independent binaries are loaded in a different place every time too.

[The Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features#aslr) has a nice summary of the different possibilities; they aren’t Ubuntu-specific.

You can disable all this (which isn’t recommended) by changing the `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` setting: 0 will disable ASLR.